# Use of "should have"

Tags: past-tense, should, have

1. It's correct to use "subject + should have + past participle" to events that didn't happen?

Example: He *should have gone* to work yesterday.

2. I can use this with "It"?

Example: It *should have been* a good friendship, but I fell in love.

Answer (score 0):

**1st** sentence sounds right

He missed a great party. He should have gone to work yesterday.

But 2nd one doesn't.

It **could have** been a great friendship but I fell in love.